# What is the c# equivalent of Class<Annotation> from java?

Tags: c#

**EDIT:** Another way to ask the question:

- if "*Class<Object>*" in Java is equivalent to "*Type*" in C#
- what's the equivalent of "*Class<Annotation>*"?

---

The code below is from a Unity3D asset I am writing, so the version of c# is quite old: " mostly but not entirely 4.0", Google tells me.

The code below works (modulo the inevitable bugs), my problem is with the expressiveness of the type signature.  The problem is with the signature of the VisitAnnotatedFields() method, specifically the attrType parameter - which is always intended to by some sub-type of Attribute.

In Java, I would define the equivalent parameter in Java as "Class<Annotation>" in order to tell the compiler that the caller must pass a subtype of Annotation.

The question isn't specific Annotations, I've had this problem before in other situations; I've just worked around it by doing the check and casting as necessary.

Is there a way to express this in C#, or do all my type references have to be "Type" and I'll need to write a bunch of documentation and code to check that the right thing is passed?

Example Code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class NotNullAttribute : Attribute {
}

class NullReferenceCheck : SceneGameObjectCheck {
  public override IEnumerable<CheckFailure> Check(MonoBehaviour target){
    var failures = new List<CheckFailure>();
    ReflectionUtils.VisitAnnotatedFields(
      target,
      typeof(NotNullAttribute),
      (FieldInfo field, Attribute attr) => {
        // do the check for null value and add to failures
      });

    return failures;
  }
}

public static void VisitAnnotatedFields(
  MonoBehaviour target,
  Type attrType,
  Action<FieldInfo, Attribute> closure)
{
  IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fieldInfos = target.GetAllFields();
  foreach( var iField in fieldInfos ){
    object[] customAttributes = iField.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    foreach( var jAttr in customAttributes ){
      if( jAttr.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(attrType) ){
        closure.Invoke(iField, (Attribute) jAttr);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: To be honnest, Unity's csharp is more "mostly but not entirely 3.5" than 4.0.

Comment: Is that relevant?  Do later versions of C# allow me to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Shorn: Off-topic, but re: `jAttr.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(attrType)`: This appears to be incorrect. This checks whether the type represented by `attrType` is of the same type as `jAttr`, or a subtype of `jAttr`'s type. I think it should be the other way around: `attrType.IsAssignableFrom(jAttr.GetType())`.

Comment: @stakx: Yeah, I'm always getting that backwards - I'll write a test, thanks.

Comment: @Shorn: Sorry, one more suggestion: If you replace `iField.GetCustomAttributes(false)` with `iField.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false)` (assuming you've implemented [Lanorkin's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26324068/240733)), you can get rid of the `IsAssignableFrom` check completely and cast the returned objects straight to `TAttribute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in general answer is NO - there's no compile type check for `Type` - I believe you can still use generics for your purpose, like this one:

```
public static void VisitAnnotatedFields<TAttribute>(
  MonoBehaviour target,
  Action<FieldInfo, TAttribute> closure)
  where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fieldInfos = target.GetAllFields();
    foreach( var iField in fieldInfos ){
      object[] customAttributes = iField.GetCustomAttributes(false);
      foreach( var jAttr in customAttributes ){
        if( jAttr.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TAttribute)) ){
          closure.Invoke(iField, (TAttribute) jAttr);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
ReflectionUtils.VisitAnnotatedFields(
  target,
  (FieldInfo field, NotNullAttribute attr) => {
    // do the check for null value and add to failures
  });
```

Which as a bonus will provide you with additional strong type inside closure itself.

Comment: Ah - yes, that does look better.  I see now: I just didn't even think about the possibility to of being able to do "typeof(TAttribute)".  Erasure's too embedded in my though process.  This may help me go back and re-visit some of those earlier problems I had - thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand Java's `Class<T>` correctly ("a `Class` object that represents type `T`"), then there is no correspondence in .NET.

There is no way in .NET to restrict *at compile-time* what types an instance of `Type` may represent. You have to do a run-time check:

```
// using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

void Foo(Type type)
{
    Contract.Requires(typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    // the above allows `type` to represent sub-types of `Attribute` as well.
    // if you want to allow only `Attribute`, change to `type == typeof(Attribute)`. 
    …
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly (why didn't I think of saying it like that).  Not the answer I wanted to hear though, to be honest.  Don't really want to write that kind of checking code in my methods, that's what compilers are for (and it's going to be very confusing for users of the API).